# how can i show incoming message at specific row in tableview in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, tableview

I am developing chat application using xmpp.I can send and receive message.My contacts are in tableview here my problem is when there is message from online user then i want show message symbol at online user row in my tableview.when that row is selected message symbol will disappear.

I tried the fallowing way using label but did not achieve

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

      XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user1= [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      cell.textLabel.text = user1.displayName;


      UILabel *lblText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(290,16,10,20)]; 
      lblText.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
      [cell addSubview:lblText];

      if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:user1.jidStr])
      {
        lblText.text=@"g";
      }



}
```

can any one help me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Incoming message store in Dictionary or Array then Reload tableview for show latest messages which arrival.

you have to Reload table view every time when message retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

use the following table view method to add new rows to the table..

```
 -insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

Your label should be added in `cell.contentView`. Table view cells have many subviews, and the one designated for your use is `contentView`.

Assuming you simplified the code for our benefit, but just in case, you have to store the message after it's come in (presumably in your Core Data object there) and call `[UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]`.

Answer (score 0):

you should refresh the NSArray which stored the table data,then  [tableView reloadData]; For example,the count of NSArray is 15,and you receive one new message, you should refresh the NSArray to contain 16 object.